# How to Setup Java Database Application Connection to both Master & Slave Servers

Tags: java, postgresql, database-connection, replication

So I have setup replication between two databases (master & slave) and the replication works correctly. Now my question is, how do I setup my application's database connection so that it connects to both master and slave server, and more importantly, how to make it read from one server if the other one is down.

I should mention that my application is written in java and I am using PostgreSQL 9.1.

Thanks!